# помогите исправить код пожалуйста

Tags: html, css

```css
a {
    color:green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE htmml>
<html>
   
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
     <title>TopStoPop</title>
     <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    </head>
   
    <bogy>
        <a href="https://www.google.ru">TopStoPop</a>!<br>
     <a href="https://www.google.ru">TopStoPop</a>!
    </bogy>
   
</html>
```

проблема кода в том что html фаел не находит css фаел. файлы находятся в одной и той же папке. помогите разобраться заранее буду благодарен 
 если выполнить код на сайте все работает. поэтому у меня есть догадка что это проблема не с кодом а оформлением файла или каких нибудь настройках 
код должен создать 2е ссылки кататорые подсвечиваются зеленым

Answer (score 1):

Вместо `<bogy>` используйте `<body>`, так же попробуйте нажать правую кнопку мыши на странице, нажмите правой кнопкой мыши на элемент (обновить страницу) в левой верхней части вашего браузера (если google chrome), и используйте (очистка кеша и жесткая перезагрузка)

Comment: спасибо но ничего не произошло. про замечание с <body> тоже большое спасибо

Comment: Как вы верстать собираетесь если банально каркас сделать не можете? Doctype поправьте: не <!DOCTYPE htmml>, а <!DOCTYPE html>

Comment: <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>

Comment: Выше шаблон от PhpStorm

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего ваш браузер закешировал прошлую версию, обновите страницу с помощью ctrl-f5

Comment: а можно это сделать без клавы а то у меня ее нет сейчас я пешу на визуальной клаве

Comment: Нажмите на адресную строку и Enter

Comment: к сожелению не работает

Comment: @Rudony Ctrl+F5 на странице для полной перезагрузки и очистки кеша.

Comment: спасибо но эту информацию я уже знаю. Серовно это не помогло( Cntr + F5